# How to make boxes fields the same size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using `HTML` and `TWIG`. 
I have different boxes with different fields filled with data retrieved from a php call. The problem is I don't know how to make those fields (and consequently boxes) the same size. 
The size of each field should be the tallest one of the group. So far I got this

[image]

As you can see, `Contratto`, `JSer` and `Azienda` are fine (usually always on a single line, so it shouldn't be a problem).

The problem is `Note`: as you can see, it goes well for single box, but having more ones just break the visualization. I'd like all fields to be the same size in their own group:

- every `Contratto` the size of the biggest one;
- every `JSer` the size of the biggest one;
- every `Azienda` the size of the biggest one
- and of course, the important one, every `Note` the size of the biggest one

Here's the code I'm using, with `Bootstrap 3.3.7`

```
{% if alerts|length > 0 %}
    <div class="box box-danger">
        <div class="box-header  with-border">
            <h3 class="box-title" style="color: #ff000f"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; I TUOI AVVISI ({{ alerts|length }})</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="box-body">
            {% for alert in alerts %}
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="shadow-box">
                        <div class="box-header  with-border">
                            <h3 class="box-title" style="color: #ff000f">Avviso</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-body">
                            <p><b>Contratto</b>: {{ alert.getJob().getContratto().getRiferimento() }}</p>
                            <p><b>JSer</b>: {{ alert.getJob().getJobStationer().getNome() }} {{ alert.getJob().getJobStationer().getCognome() }}</p>
                            <p><b>Azienda</b>: {{ alert.getJob().getAzienda().getNome() }}</p>
                            <p><b>Note</b>: {{ alert.getJob().getNote() }}</p>
                        </div>

                        {% if alert.getUtente() is not null %}
                            <div class="box-footer" style="text-align: left">
                                <p><b>Modificato da</b> {{ alert.getUtente().getNome() }} {{ alert.getUtente().getCognome() }} <b>il</b> {{ alert.getDataModifica()|date('d/m/Y') }}</p>
                            </div>
                        {% endif %}

                        <div class="box-footer">
                            <a href="{{ path('job_dettaglio', { 'id_job': alert.getJob().getId(), 'dettaglio': 1 }) }}"class="link-avviso">
                                Vai al dettaglio <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

EDIT: this is the code version with columns and rows

```
{% if alerts|length > 0 %}
    <div class="box box-danger">
        <div class="box-header  with-border">
            <h3 class="box-title" style="color: #ff000f"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; I TUOI AVVISI ({{ alerts|length }})</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="box-body">
            {% for alert in alerts %}
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="shadow-box">
                        <div class="box-header  with-border">
                            <h3 class="box-title" style="color: #ff000f">Avviso</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <b>Contratto</b>: {{ alert.getJob().getContratto().getRiferimento() }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <b>JSer</b>: {{ alert.getJob().getJobStationer().getNome() }} {{ alert.getJob().getJobStationer().getCognome() }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <b>Azienda</b>: {{ alert.getJob().getAzienda().getNome() }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <b>Note</b>: {{ alert.getJob().getNote() }}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        {% if alert.getUtente() is not null %}
                            <div class="box-footer" style="text-align: left">
                                <p><b>Modificato da</b> {{ alert.getUtente().getNome() }} {{ alert.getUtente().getCognome() }} <b>il</b> {{ alert.getDataModifica()|date('d/m/Y') }}</p>
                            </div>
                        {% endif %}

                        <div class="box-footer">
                            <a href="{{ path('job_dettaglio', { 'id_job': alert.getJob().getId(), 'dettaglio': 1 }) }}"class="link-avviso">
                                Vai al dettaglio <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Any suggestion?

EDIT ANSWER:
After few tries, I normalized the single row instead of single fields...single fields would not be the same height, but the row will, so this is actually fine for my final result. Here's the answer:

```
//CSS in head
.alertProperties {
   padding-left:0px !important;
}

//Code
{% if alerts|length > 0 %}
    <div class="box box-danger">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
            <h3 class="box-title" style="color: #ff000f"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; I TUOI AVVISI ({{ alerts|length }})</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="box-body">
            {% for alert in alerts %}
                {% if loop.index % 5 == 0 or loop.first %}                                   
                    <div class="row">
                {% endif %}
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                            <div class="box-header with-border"><h3 class="box-title" style="color: #ff000f">Avviso</h3></div>
                            <div class="box-body" style="border-left: 1px solid #00ACDF !important">
                                <div class="col-sm-12 alertProperties">
                                    <b>Contratto</b>: {{ alert.getJob().getContratto().getRiferimento() }}
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-12 alertProperties">
                                    <b>JSer</b>: {{ alert.getJob().getJobStationer().getNome() }} {{ alert.getJob().getJobStationer().getCognome() }}
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-12 alertProperties">
                                    <b>Azienda</b>: {{ alert.getJob().getAzienda().getNome() }}
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-12 alertProperties">
                                    <b>Note</b>: {{ alert.getJob().getNote() }}</p>
                                </div>

                                {% if alert.getUtente() is not null %}
                                    <div class="box-footer" style="text-align:left;">
                                        <div class="col-sm-12 alertProperties">
                                            <b>Modificato da</b> {{ alert.getUtente().getNome() }} {{ alert.getUtente().getCognome() }} <b>il</b> {{ alert.getDataModifica()|date('d/m/Y') }}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                {% endif %}

                                <div class="box-footer">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <a href="{{ path('job_dettaglio', { 'id_job': alert.getJob().getId(), 'dettaglio': 1 }) }}" class="link-avviso">
                                            Vai al dettaglio <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                {% if (loop.index % 4 == 0 or loop.last) %}
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {# </div> #}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height)

Comment: @DarkBee not really, because those answers start from the assumption that we have different column inside a row. But I have different boxes and different rows, one for each field...it's the same argument, but different question

Comment: Read into the [flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22892773/446594) solution they provide. That should do the trick

Answer (score -1):

You can truncate text of the note section by forcing text on the same line with the `white-space:none`

```
p{ 
  
  width:400px;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

However if you wanna truncate it to more than one line  you can read it more on [chris  coyier's article here](https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/)